# Computing ACF of Time Series Process

Tags: time-series, covariance

I need to compute the ACF of the following process: $X_t = \frac{1}{4}X_{t-1} + Z_t$, where $Z_t$ is a white noise process with variance 1. My work so far: $$Cov(X_t, X_{t+h}) = Cov(\frac{1}{4}X_{t-1} + Z_t, \frac{1}{4}X_{t+h-1} + Z_{t+h}) = Cov(\frac{1}{4}X_{t-1}, \frac{1}{4}X_{t+h-1}) + Cov(\frac{1}{4}X_{t-1}, Z_{t+h}) + Cov(Z_t, \frac{1}{4}X_{t+h-1}) + Cov(Z_t, Z_{t+h}).$$ Now, my thinking is that we have to consider a few cases. If $|h| \geq 2$, then we get $0.$ If $h = 0$, then we get $\frac{1}{16}Var(X_{t-1}) + ??.$ I'm stuck now, both with finding the next few terms and with finding $Var(X_{t-1}).$ Thanks for any help!

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/335462/475077)

Comment: @Dayne Thanks for the link! Very helpful.